# Preloading part of HDF5 file while performing other task

Tags: python, multithreading, loading, h5py

I'm training a deep learning classifier, which uses a HDF5 dataset that is too large to fit into memory. Therefore, I extract the data in batches of 256 and use these batches to train my classifier in the following way. The deep learning library that I use (Keras) provides the method `model.train_on_batch(X_batch, y_batch)`.

```
for i in range(n_batches_in_dset):
        X_batch, y_batch = load_partition('train', ind=[i*batch_size, (i+1)*batch_size])
        loss = model.train_on_batch(X_batch, y_batch)
```

It would make sense to prefetch the next batch of data while training on the current data using the GPU. How can do this in Python?

I've attached the code that I use for loading the data.

```
def load_hdf5(path, datapart, ind=None):
    f   = h5py.File(path, 'r')
    if ind is None:
        dat = f[datapart][:]
    else:
        dat = f[datapart][ind[0]:ind[1]]
    f.close()
    return np.array(dat)

def load_partition(name, ind=None):
    path = DEEP_ROOT + 'data/{}.h5'.format(name)
    X = load_hdf5(path, 'data', ind)
    y = load_hdf5(path, 'label', ind)
    X = np.swapaxes(X, 2, 3)
    y = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
    return X, y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably the simplest thing to do is put the separate tasks in separate [threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects), with a synchronized [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) to hand the batches between them.  We'll use a separate thread for the data-reading part, and the main thread for the training portion.

```
import Queue, threading

data_queue = Queue.Queue(2) # a queue with two space for two "chunks"
sentinel = object()

#start the data-loading task
def load_task()
    for x in i in range(n_batches_in_dset):
        data_queue.put(load_partition('train', ind=[i*batch_size, (i+1)*batch_size]), True)
    # tell the other side we're "done"
    data_queue.put(sentinel, True)

threading.Thread(target=load_task).start()

while True:
    batch = data_queue.get(True)
    data_queue.task_done()
    if batch is sentinel:
        break # we're done now!
    X_batch, y_batch = batch
    loss = model.train_on_batch(X_batch, y_batch)
```

**EDIT**: we need to use `Queue.task_done()` to unblock the queue

Comment: Instead of loading each batch (256 observations), it would actually make more sense to preload 20% of the dataset (20000 observations) and move all of it to the GPU. This way, both IO from disc and to GPU is significantly reduced. Do you know how I can move the data to the GPU explicitly?

Comment: Nope, i don't know the first thing about the tools you're using, other than what you've described in your question.  This answer if from a "general python problem solving" perspective.